# Switching between multiple tables at runtime in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am working in an environment where we have separate tables for each client (this is something which I can't change due to security and other requirements).  For example, if we have clients ACME and MEGAMART then we'd have an ACME_INFO table and MEGAMART_INFO tables and both tables would have the same structure (let's say ID, SOMEVAL1, SOMEVAL2).

I would like to have a way to easily access the different tables dynamically.

To this point I've dealt with this in a few ways including:

1. Using dynamic SQL in procedures/functions (not fun)
2. Creating a view which does a UNION ALL on all of the tables and which adds a CLIENT_ID COLUMN (i.e. "CREATE VIEW COMBINED_VIEW AS SELECT 'ACME' CLIENT_ID, ID, SOMEVAL1, SOMEVAL2 FROM ACME_INFO UNION ALL SELECT 'MEGMART' CLIENT_ID, ID, SOMEVAL1, SOMEVAL2") which performs surprisingly well, but is a pain to maintain and kind of defeats some of the requirements which dictate that we have separate tables for each client.
3. SYNONYMs won't work because we need different connections to act on different clients
4. A view which refers to a package which has a package variable for the active client.  This is just evil and doesn't even work out all that well.

What I'd really like is to be able to create a table function, macro, or something else where I can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM FN_CLIENT_INFO('ACME');
```

or even

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM FN_CLIENT_INFO('ACME')) SET SOMEVAL1 = 444 WHERE ID = 3;
```

I know that I can partially achieve this with a pipelined function, but this mechanism will need to be used by a reporting platform and if the reporting platform does something like

```
SELECT * FROM FN_CLIENT_INFO('ACME') WHERE SOMEVAL1 = 4
```

then I want it to run efficiently (assuming SOMEVAL1 has an index for example).  This is where a macro would do well.

Macros seem like a good solution, but the above won't work due to protections put in place to prevent against SQL injection.

Is there a way to create a macro that somehow verifies that the passed in VARCHAR2 is a valid table name and therefore can be used or is there some other approach to address what I need?

I was thinking that if I had a function which could translate a client name to a DBMS_TF.TABLE_T then I could use a macro, but I haven't found a way to do that well.

Comment: Another problem you may encounter with MACRO (and PTF) is that you can't pass the table name as a VARCHAR2, it must be a DBMS_TF.table_t but how many reporting tools are supporting the syntax "SELECT ... FROM function(table)" (without quotes around the parameter) as yet few support the syntax "SELECT ... FROM function('parameter')"... ? At least not SAP/BO neither Tableau... (so even with pipelined function you may encounter problems). So you should start by analyzing the reporting tool possibilities... guessing you want to avoid having a different reporting universe per customer.

Comment: If each client uses its own username, then you absolutely should use synonyms to solve this. A set of private synonyms in each schema would point to the correct table for the corresponding client. This also allows you to lock down your security better, in that you can provide no read privs at all to tables that don't belong to them.

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly this works: "different connections to act on different clients". Does every client have only one user, and that user can only see that one client's tables? If so, you can combine Virtual Private Database (VPD) with the view approach to ensure security; when the user connects a logon trigger sets a variable defining who the client is, and with VPD you can force the optimizer to always rewrite `SELECT * FROM COMBINED_VIEW` to `SELECT * FROM COMBINED_VIEW WHERE CLIENT_ID = get_client_id()`. There may also be some tricks to help with maintenance and allowing updates.

Comment: Sorry to not be clear.  The clients do not log in themselves.  These are tables used by internal systems.

Comment: @ajz You should still look into VPD and see if it could help. It was designed for situations like this, where you need to be absolutely certain that user's can only see data they have permission to. Normally, the system is built on top of tables, but it could probably work with views as well. Although you'll need some way to ensure that the session always identifies itself as the proper client before querying the database. Or maybe this feature could help you convince management that the one-large-table approach is both easier and more secure when you add this feature on top of it.

Comment: Jon, thanks for your input.  Our clients do not access their tables.  Our job is to collect data for the client, perform analysis on it, etc.  This involves automated systems (some in PL/SQL, some using other technologies) which have access to all client tables as well as human analysts who need temporary access to client tables as they perform their work.  I will look into VPDs more closely to see if they would help.

Answer (score 1):

A lesser-known method for such cases is to use a system-partitioned table. For instance, consider the following code:

Full example: https://dbfiddle.uk/UQsAgHCk

```sql
create table t_common(a int, b int)
  partition by system (
     partition ACME_INFO,
     partition MEGAMART_INFO
  );

insert into t_common partition(acme_info)
  values(1,1);
insert into t_common partition(megamart_info)
  values(2,2);
commit;

select * from t_common partition(acme_info);
select * from t_common partition(megamart_info);
```

As demonstrated, a common table can be used with different partitions for different clients, allowing it to be used as a regular table. We can create a system-partitioned table and utilize the exchange partition feature with older tables. Then, we can drop the older tables and create views with the same names, so that older code continues to work with views while all new code can work with the common table by specifying a partition.

Comment: Sayan, thank  you for your response.  Unfortunately due to things beyond my control the data has to be in separate tables.  Part of this is that we need to have different permissions (which change over time) for each client table.  For example, one of our analysts my need to look into something in one of our client's tables. That analyst would be granted read access on that table during the duration of that work.

Comment: @ajz so, no problem at all: just grant permissions on those replacement views